# Too many scroll events for smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello there I've been trying to find a fix for the many scroll events firing on one scroll. This is the only thing close to working for me so far. I want to smoothscroll between two divs (#boxes and #header) I want to use the scroll bar to trigger this smooth scroll and not a button. Any suggestions on how to only take one scroll event? I also used solutions based from prev stackoverflow questions. I used my own locator instead of offsets because thats also unreliable

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (locator == 0) {
            id      = $("#boxes");
            locator = 1;
        } else if (locator = 1) {
            id      = $("#header");
            locator = 0;
        }


        // target element
        var $id = $(id);
        if ($id.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        // top position relative to the document
        var pos = $id.offset().top;

        // animated top scrolling
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1500, function () {
            $('html, body').clearQueue();
            $('html, body').stop();
        });

    }, 2);

});
```

Comment: For starters, the `if (timer) {` code block should be below `timer = window.setTimeout(function () {` block. Otherwise variable `timer` would be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to be clear, you want any minor scroll event to scroll between one item and the other? Note that when a user scrolls, there is a "momentum" that the browser implements, and you'll be battling with that.

Regardless: You don't need to wrap this in a `setTimeout`. Right now, your javascript is creating a new `setTimeout` function that is being fired every 2ms. Scroll events occur with every pixel of movement in the scroll, so if you scroll 100px, you're going to be firing 100 times every 2ms. (That's 50,000 times).

Instead, have a a variable (`isScrolling`) track the state, so, if you're in the middle of scrolling, the function won't fire.

```
var isScrolling = false;
var locator = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {

  if (isScrolling) return false;

  if (locator == 0) {
    id      = $("#boxes");
    locator = 1;
  } else if (locator = 1) {
    id      = $("#header");
    locator = 0;
  }


  // target element
  var $id = $(id);
  if ($id.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  // top position relative to the document
  var pos = $id.offset().top;

  // animated top scrolling
  isScrolling = true;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1500, function () {
    $('html, body').clearQueue();
    $('html, body').stop();
    isScrolling = false;
  });


});
```

Here's a JSbin: http://jsbin.com/jugefup/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked now for me. I had been trying to deal with the multiple scroll events for quite a while. You're a life saver I'm new to stackoverflow so If I knew how to upvote this I woud